# Anchored image in table cell not sizing to cell width

Tags: css, html, image, html-table

Fairly new to HTML5 and CSS. I'm trying to adjust the size of an image in a table cell and it doesn't size to the size of the cell - any help would be appreciated!

Link: http://mercury.ict.swin.edu.au/cos10020/s100505453/techno_syndicate/index.htm

**HTML**

```
        <div class="artists">
        <table>
            <caption>
                <h1>Artists</h1>
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/adrian_hour.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/anna.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/carl_craig.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/danny_daze.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/dubfire.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/kink.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/matrixxman.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/mr_g.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/nicole_moudaber.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/nikola_gala.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/oliver_huntemann.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/radio_slave.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/scuba.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/spencer_parker.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><img src="img/artists/uto_karem.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#homepage .artists {
    width: 70vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(#E7E8D6, #B9C2D7);
    margin: auto;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#homepage .artists > table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#homepage .artists > table > caption > h1 {
    font-family: "SF Funk Master";
    font-size: 64px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #003663;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#homepage .artists > table > tr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33.33%;
}

#homepage .artists > table > tr > td {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

#homepage .artists > table > tr > td > a > img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
#homepage .artists > table > tr > td > a > img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

to

```
.artists table img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

That should work.

Here is a JSFiddle for you to play with https://jsfiddle.net/4paqqmg2/

Comment: Fixed it - thanks a bunch! Can you tell me the difference in using '>' and not using it?

Comment: > is direct child to 'li > a > img' will affect <li><a href=""><img> but not <li><a href=""><p><img> while li img will affect both.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your img rule for max-width, `max-width: 100%;` is overriding your `width: 20%;` rule for `td`.  A width setting will be overridden by min-width and max-width.  So just set an appropriate width to your `img` tag, i.e., you can do `img { width: 20%;  }` for example, and all your images will fit into place.  Also, to keep the aspect ratio of your images, just set width or height.